# How do I make my custom loss function scalar?

Tags: pytorch, reinforcement-learning

I am coding a dqn from scratch and therefore have written my loss function. While calling backward on my loss function, I get the following error - `RuntimeError: grad can be implicitly created only for scalar outputs`

Here's my code -

```
import numpy as np
import gym
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import os
import torch
import random
from torch import nn
from torch.utils.data import DataLoader
from torchvision import datasets, transforms
from collections import deque 
import sys
env = gym.make("CliffWalking-v0")


# In[103]:


#Hyperparameters
episodes = 5000
eps = 1.0
learning_rate = 0.1
discount_factor = 0.99
tot_rewards = []
decay_val = 0.001
mem_size = 50000
batch_size = 2
gamma = 0.99


# In[104]:


class NeuralNetwork(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, state_size, action_size):
        super(NeuralNetwork, self).__init__()
        self.state_size = state_size
        self.action_size = action_size
        self.linear_relu_stack = nn.Sequential(
            nn.Linear(1, 30),
            nn.ReLU(),
            nn.Linear(30, 30),
            nn.ReLU(),
            nn.Linear(30, action_size)
        )
    def forward(self, x):
        x = self.linear_relu_stack(x)
        return x


# In[105]:


model = NeuralNetwork(env.observation_space.n, env.action_space.n)
opt = torch.optim.Adam(params=model.parameters(), lr=learning_rate)
loss = nn.MSELoss()
replay_buffer = deque(maxlen=mem_size)


# In[106]:


state = torch.tensor(env.reset(), dtype=torch.float32)
state = state.unsqueeze(dim=0)
print(state.shape)
out = model(state)


# In[111]:


def compute_td_loss(batch_size):
    state, next_state, reward, done, action = zip(*random.sample(replay_buffer, batch_size))
    state = torch.from_numpy(np.array(state).reshape(-1, 1)).unsqueeze(dim = 0).type(torch.float32)
    next_state = torch.from_numpy(np.array(next_state).reshape(-1, 1)).unsqueeze(dim = 0).type(torch.float32)
    reward = torch.from_numpy(np.array(reward))
    done = torch.from_numpy(np.array(done))
    action = torch.from_numpy(np.array(action)).type(torch.int64)
    q_values = model(state)
    next_q_values = model(next_state)
    q_vals = q_values.squeeze().gather(dim=-1, index=action.reshape(-1,1)).reshape(1, -1)
    max_next_q_values = torch.max(next_q_values,2)[0].detach()
    print("q_vals = ", q_vals)
    print("max_next_q_values = ", max_next_q_values)
    loss = 0.5*(reward + gamma*max_next_q_values - q_vals)**2
    print("reward = ", reward)
    print("loss = ", loss)
    opt.zero_grad()
    loss.backward()
    opt.step()
    return loss
    


# In[112]:


for i in range(episodes):
    state = env.reset()
    done = False
    steps = 0
    eps_rew = 0 
    while not done and steps<50:
        if np.random.uniform(0,1)<eps:
            action = env.action_space.sample()
        else:
            state = torch.tensor(state, dtype=torch.float32)
            state = state.unsqueeze(dim=0)
            action = np.argmax(model(state).detach().numpy())
        next_state, reward, done, info = env.step(action)
        replay_buffer.append((state, next_state, reward, done, action))
        if len(replay_buffer)>batch_size:
            loss = compute_td_loss(batch_size)
            sys.exit()
        eps = eps/(1 + 0.001)
        eps_rew += reward 
        if done:
            break
        state = next_state
    tot_rewards.append(eps_rew)
```

Here's the error that I get -

```
RuntimeError                              Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-112-015fd74c95d9> in <module>
     14         replay_buffer.append((state, next_state, reward, done, action))
     15         if len(replay_buffer)>batch_size:
---> 16             loss = compute_td_loss(batch_size)
     17             sys.exit()
     18         eps = eps/(1 + 0.001)

<ipython-input-111-3e1e02c32b4f> in compute_td_loss(batch_size)
     16     print("loss = ", loss)
     17     opt.zero_grad()
---> 18     loss.backward()
     19     opt.step()
     20     return loss

c:\users\thoma\anaconda3\envs\custom_atari_env\lib\site-packages\torch\_tensor.py in backward(self, gradient, retain_graph, create_graph, inputs)
    253                 create_graph=create_graph,
    254                 inputs=inputs)
--> 255         torch.autograd.backward(self, gradient, retain_graph, create_graph, inputs=inputs)
    256 
    257     def register_hook(self, hook):

c:\users\thoma\anaconda3\envs\custom_atari_env\lib\site-packages\torch\autograd\__init__.py in backward(tensors, grad_tensors, retain_graph, create_graph, grad_variables, inputs)
    141 
    142     grad_tensors_ = _tensor_or_tensors_to_tuple(grad_tensors, len(tensors))
--> 143     grad_tensors_ = _make_grads(tensors, grad_tensors_)
    144     if retain_graph is None:
    145         retain_graph = create_graph

c:\users\thoma\anaconda3\envs\custom_atari_env\lib\site-packages\torch\autograd\__init__.py in _make_grads(outputs, grads)
     48             if out.requires_grad:
     49                 if out.numel() != 1:
---> 50                     raise RuntimeError("grad can be implicitly created only for scalar outputs")
     51                 new_grads.append(torch.ones_like(out, memory_format=torch.preserve_format))
     52             else:

RuntimeError: grad can be implicitly created only for scalar outputs
```

Comment: What is the shape of `loss` ?

Comment: The shape of my loss is torch.Size([1, 2])

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given that your `batch_size = 2` and looking at your code your `loss` will likely be of size `batch_size x 1`. Given that what you are likely trying to do is to compute the gradient of **expected** Q loss you can use monte carlo estimator where instead of computing an expectation we use a mean over a finite sample (here - your batch). Consequently what you are missing is taking a **mean** of your loss before calling backwards.

Comment: Could you please elaborate on using an monte carlo estimator instead of mean? How would the loss function change? Thanks a lot for your help!

Comment: Also, I kept the batch size = 2 just for debugging purposes. Once I run my code, it'll definitely be higher :)

Comment: Monte carlo estimator is exactly what you are doing - to take an average over a sample to approximate expectation. It is just a mathematical object that describes the procedure you are following